# Colocar tags scripts em react native

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

Como faço para colocar tags javascript no react native?

Tenho essa tag para colocar num projeto

```
<script data-cfasync='false' type='text/javascript' src='link'></script>
```

É uma tag de um anúncio.

No navegador funciona. Porém não sei como inserir no react native.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Acredito que não seja possível fazer isso que você necessita, talvez possa utilizar o WebView https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview.html

Comment: Eu achei esse site: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-load-script vou tentar pra ver.